# Where does flash player save permanent files to, like game saves, or configurations?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, flash

I'd like to grab a copy of a save file I have for a flash game (to be fair, there's at least 20 hours of gaming in that save).

I assume that different browsers and different operating systems do their own thing, but to know how different browser/OS combos do things would be useful extra information.

I use google chrome and I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Linux: `~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/`
- Windows: `%AppData%\Macromedia\Flash Player\`
- Mac OS X: `~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/`

Plugin behavior, and therefore Flash LSO location, is browser-independent most of the time.

Also see [Local Shared Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object#File_locations) on Wikipedia.

Comment: this no longer seems to be true for Mac OS X. Chrome saves to ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 12.04, I found Google Chrome's flash plugin also stores LSOs in

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/
```

More specifically, I found my game saves in

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another folder to look at is:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System/p/00`

Those last two folders might be called differently because of randomization, but I found that, even after I cleaned my cache a few times, looked at the locations of the above mentioned comments, there was still a very big file with no special name or file extension stored there.

It would've been very unlikely that Chrome need this to function.