# Where does the ruffle flash player save permanent files to, like game saves, or configurations?

Tags: flash-player

As this question and answer seems to be horribly outdated:
[Where does flash player save permanent files to, like game saves, or configurations?](https://superuser.com/questions/259686/where-does-flash-player-save-permanent-files-to-like-game-saves-or-configurati)

is there something similar for the ruffle flash player?

Comment: Probably best to ask on the discord https://ruffle.rs/ & https://discord.gg/ruffle

Comment: There are easy ways to detect this yourself. Process Monitor is a popular tool, also e.g. Everything with sorting by date modified can show it really quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where does the ruffle flash player save permanent files to?

> Ruffle writes Flash save data into [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). Local Storage is stored client-side and not on the server. However, Flash content could send the data to a server via an HTTP request (see below). Storage in Flash happens through the use of `SharedObject`.

Source: [infos: How does Ruffle handle Flashcookies - Data Protection - External Calls · ruffle-rs/ruffle · Discussion #3042 · GitHub](https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle/discussions/3042)

---

#### So where is browser `Window:localStorage` located?

It depends on what browser you are running:

> Storage of web storage objects is enabled by default in current versions of all supporting web browsers, with browser vendors providing ways for users to natively enable or disable web storage, or clear the web storage "cache".[17] Similar controls over web storage are also available through 3rd party browser extensions. Each browser stores Web storage objects differently:
>
> - Firefox saves Web storage objects in a SQLite file called webappsstore.sqlite in the user's profile folder.
> - Google Chrome records Web storage data in a SQLite file in the user's profile. The subfolder containing this file is
>   "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage" on
>   Windows, and "~/Library/Application
>   Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage" on macOS.
> - Opera's Web storage is located in either "\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\sessions\autosave.win" or
>   "\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\pstorage" depending upon Opera's version.
> - Internet Explorer's Web storage is "\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStorage".
> - Safari's Web Storage is located in a folder labeled "LocalStorage" within a hidden "safari" folder.

Source [Web storage - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage)

For Edge see [local storage - Where does Microsoft Edge save localstorage on a computer under windows 10? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328691/where-does-microsoft-edge-save-localstorage-on-a-computer-under-windows-10)

Comment: Apparently you can also just right click the flash application and as of right now it opens a context menu where you can download the .swf, but also access the "Save Manager", which offers a GUI to download, delete and replace data stored by that app in case one doesn't want to deal with the sql database. Though anyway massive thank you for the answer!